# Need to retrieve vmware instance UUId for multiple instances

Tags: terraform, vmware

I am provisioning multiple vm's using below templates:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each                = var.vms
  name                    = each.value.name 
  folder                  = var.vsphere_folder
  num_cpus                = var.vm_cpus
  memory                  = var.vm_memory
  firmware                = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.firmware
  efi_secure_boot_enabled = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.efi_secure_boot_enabled
  guest_id                = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id
  scsi_type               = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
  datastore_id            = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  resource_pool_id        = data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id
}
```

I am looking to retrieve the uuid of these 6 instances as below and it does not work:

```
vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.*.uuid
```

How can I get the UUID's?

Code where I am using it:

```
module abc {
  source   = "../../abc"
  for_each = var.vms
  re       = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.*.uuid
}
```

Comment: count VS for_each ... that `vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.*.uuid` is the syntax if you had count

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I am assigning the result of "vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.*.uuid" into a string variable and it gives me an error - The given value is not suitable for variable defined.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Okay, now I understand that the above mentioned syntax is for count. So what can I use to get UUID when I am using for_each

Comment: looking from the comments here and on the answer below I think you should add a bit more code to get a complete picture ... where are you using those uuid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see where your confusion is and I think is best clarified with an example:

```hcl
locals {
  vm = {
    "big" = {
      "uuid" = "foo"
      "name" = "my abc vm"
    },
    "small" = {
      "uuid" = "bar"
      "name" = "my def vm"
    }
  }
}

output "data" {
  value = values(local.vm)[*].uuid
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  for_each = local.vm

  triggers = {
    key = each.key
    uuid = each.value.uuid
    name = each.value.name
  }
}
```

in this example the `local.vm` is the equivalent to your `vsphere_virtual_machine.vm`

if we just need the list we can do with the value function as [suggested by Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78130071/7599833) but if we need to pass information to another resource or a module we can loop with the `for_each` like you did initially in your vm

---

Your module will look something like

```
module abc {
  source   = "../../abc"
  for_each = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm
  re       = each.value.uuid
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but I did not understand 1 part. uuid is generated once the server is provisioned so that will not be available to local vm variable right? I have also deifined vm variable as map of objects which has only name. So how can we use each.value.uuid to pass it to other module

Comment: correct that is not available in your case until you do `terraform apply` but the idea is the same the you get a map of objects that you can extract the values using the `value(` function or loop with a `for_each`

Comment: See the second part... I was still editing my answer when you commented

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output all the values for a given attribute when using the `for_each` meta-argument, you can use the [`values` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values):

```
output "vm_uuids" {
  value = values(vsphere_virtual_machine.vm)[*].uuid
}
```

EDIT: As per the added code, the change should be as follows for this to work:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each                = var.vms
  name                    = each.value.name 
  folder                  = var.vsphere_folder
  num_cpus                = var.vm_cpus
  memory                  = var.vm_memory
  firmware                = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.firmware
  efi_secure_boot_enabled = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.efi_secure_boot_enabled
  guest_id                = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id
  scsi_type               = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
  datastore_id            = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  resource_pool_id        = data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id
}

module abc {
  source   = "../../abc"
  for_each = var.vms
  re       = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm[each.key].uuid
}
```

Alternatively, you could use resource chaining with `for_each`:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each                = var.vms
  name                    = each.value.name 
  folder                  = var.vsphere_folder
  num_cpus                = var.vm_cpus
  memory                  = var.vm_memory
  firmware                = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.firmware
  efi_secure_boot_enabled = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.efi_secure_boot_enabled
  guest_id                = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id
  scsi_type               = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
  datastore_id            = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  resource_pool_id        = data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id
}

module abc {
  source   = "../../abc"
  for_each = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm
  re       = each.value.uuid
}
```

Comment: I am assigning the result of "vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.*.uuid" into a string variable and it gives me an error - The given value is not suitable for variable defined.

Comment: I understand that this syntax provides list but I just need to retrieve the uuid of 1 instance at a time during for each execution and assign it to string variable